# How to do get the Retries tab with retries instead of several test with the same name in the Allure report?

Tags: junit5, allure

I generate the Allure report after launch a test with @RepeatedIfExceptionsTest tag with the graldew test command but got several separated tests with the same name. The Retries tab is empty. [How to do get the Retries tab with retries instead of several test with the same name in the report?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7H6y.png)

```
    @Issue("123")
    @Flaky
    @Link(value = "Link1")
    @TmsLink(value = "TmsLink1")
    @Issue(value = "Issue11")
    @Tag(value = "tmp")
    @RepeatedIfExceptionsTest(name = "Find even number", repeats = 3)
    public void findEvenNumberTest(){
        int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 3);
        assertEquals(randomNum%2, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Retries tab is responsible for history of your test runs. So when you run a test 2 times and generate your report then on Retries tab you'll see 2 runs.

Retries tab gets json files that are created after each run. But I guess that when within one run you execute a test 3 times then it's result will be stored in 1 json file so Retries tab won't take it as it needs 2 or more json report files.

So you just misunderstood functionality of Retries tab.

Another tricky tab is History. It's almost the same as Retries but based on info from this tab, the widget on the main page is generated. To make History tab not empty you need to copy "/report/history" folder to "/allure-results/history" and then regenerate your report from "/allure-results"